# GcmReceiver cannot be found

Tags: android

I have old library which has `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` but I would need to use `com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver`;
I imported `google-play-services_lib` (I have to use older version because I inherited a lot of old code which need old version) and `support-library-v7 ( contains also v4 )` but for some reason cannot find `GcmReceiver`. Is there anyway that I can download .jar file which contains `com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver` ?

Comment: Which version of Google Play Services did you load?

Comment: @Lingviston I have this in manifest in folder of imported google play services android:versionCode="5077000" android:versionName="5.0.77-000" package="com.google.android.gms"

Comment: No, check in the place where you loaded it. AFAIK new Push Notifications API available since GMS v7.8.0 maybe a little bit older. If you're using old library version - you have to update. There's nothing difficult cause new classed are just default implementations of common ways to implement older API. So if you already have BroadcastReceiver which handles your PN then you don't need GCMRecevier.